# o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound : Request method 'POST' not supported

Tags: angularjs, node.js, maven, spring-boot, gruntjs

I was deploying a project downloaded from GitHub, everything have done, and the main class of server is:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Controller
@EnableDiscoveryClient

    public class AdminUIApplication {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(AdminUIApplication.class, args);
        }

        @RequestMapping(value = "/fe/**")
        public String redirect() {
            return "forward:/";
        }

    }
```

URL:http://localhost:8451/fe/login was entered and then click LOGIN IN , but I always get the error from the back-end log: o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound : Request method 'POST' not supported.
The information of front-end as shown below:[front-end information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyH5J.png)

From the information of Request URL: localhost:8451/uaa/oauth/token, actually it cannot be accessed since the token service is provided by another server also run on the local machine which port is 8080, and I have tried with 8080 to access the service, the result is OK. So, I think, this is the reason of this error, but I have no idea how to correct it, so I post the problem here to ask for your help. Sorry that I just provided the general information about the project/code because I am not sure which piece of code should post, if you need something other information or code, please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@W.Zhou The controller should be in your server code, i.e. in Spring, because apparently Spring Boot creates a default handler only for GET requests. However, `return "forward:/";` maintains the POST method in your case. So if you want to forward the request as POST, you need to create a controller for it:

`@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String redirect2() {
        return "viewName";
    }`

Another possibility is that you have a controller in Angular which handles "/" GET request. So you can also try returning `"redirect:/"` instead of `"forward:/"`in your `redirect()` method.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `redirect` method redirects to `http://localhost:8451/` with POST and there is no controller available to handle it. Do you have a controller with `@RequestMapping(value = "/")` ?

Comment: I think so, but the client is built via AngularJS which I know little about it , and it is hard for me to find where the controller is. May I ask where the controller is for such structure typically? In addition, what my request is to access uaa server (spring boot application) deployed with port 8080, do you think the request mapping will be configured in *.yml on uaa application